Question about finding generators of the kernel for a substitution maps in rings.
The following is taken from Abstract Algebra A Comprehensive Introduction by: Lawerence and Zorzitto.
Background
Exercsie 6:  Find generators for the kernel of each of the following substitution maps:
$(a)$ $R[X]\to\Bbb{C}$ where $f(X)\mapsto f(1+2i).$
Questions
If I have the substitution map $\phi_a(f(a))=f(1+2i)$ by the way the question is asking for "generators for the kernel", am I suppose to figure out first what the kernel is suppose to be, which is $\langle X^2+2X+2\rangle$.  Then what am I suppose to do after?
Thank you in advavnce.

What is $R$? If $R = \mathbb{R}$ then it doesn't contain $1 + 2i$ so you have to work harder than that to figure out what the kernel is. Then the kernel is some ideal, and it has some generators as an ideal (do you know what this means?), and you are supposed to find some.

@QiaochuYuan I am not sure what "generators for the kernel" means.  Also, I edited my post.  I made a mistake when I wrote $a=1+2i$.  I think the kernel is an ideal containing a multiple of a polynomial in $\Bbb{R}[X]$.  I am not sure how to find it. I have a feeling it is a second degree polynomial.

Do you know what it means to generate an ideal? Also, what is $a$?

@QiaochuYuan to generate an ideal means the multiples of the elements of an ideal., like if you have a single element $a\in R$ and you can create a principal ideal of $(a)$ by writing out all the multiples of $a$.

Yes, that's what "generators for the kernel" means. It means to find elements which generate the kernel as an ideal. (Actually you will only need one element. Start by trying to write down any nonzero element of the kernel at all.)

@QiaochuYuan I edit my post.  The kernel should be $\langle X^2+2X+2\rangle$.  I simply used the quadratic formula to work backwards.  But I am not sure if this is what the question is asking.  Also if the kernel of a map is in the form of a polynomial $g(x)$ say, should the generator for the kernel contains a multiple of that polynomial $g(x)$ by all polynomial in the form of $p(x)g(x)$ for all $p(x)\in R[x]$?

Yes, that's correct, and that's what the question is asking. The kernel is an ideal, not a polynomial. If it is the ideal $\langle g(X) \rangle$ that is saying, by definition, that $g(X)$ generates that ideal, so $g(X)$ is a generator of the ideal. You seem to be very confused about some linguistic point here but I can't tell what it is. Is it the difference between "generates" and "generators"?

@QiaochuYuan i have issues with language comprehension.

The generator for the kernel doesn't look right: I think it should be $X^2 - 2X + 5$.

@ViktorVaughan yes you are right.  Thank you for pointing out my mistake.
